# What is the performance difference between strand.post and strand.wrap?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

What is the performance difference between `strand::post()` and `strand::wrap()`? And what's the story about race condition when use `strand::wrap(`)?

Comment: Please elaborate on the race condition part of your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for clarification, [`strand::wrap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/wrap.html) only creates a handler, neither the provided handler nor returned handler are dispatched or posted to the `io_service`.  If the result from `strand::wrap` is executed, then performance differences from overhead is negligible.  However, a perceived performance difference could occur as the result of the wrapped handler using [`dispatch()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/dispatch.html), where under certain conditions the user's handler will be executed immediately, instead of [`post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/post.html), where the user's handler is always added to the queue.

Also, there should be no race conditions when using a strand.  Per the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html), it is thread safe for distinct and shared objects.